# How to reproduce the class methods behavior in C99?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a simple code to calculate a polygon perimeter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

struct point { float x; float y; };

struct polygon
{
    int sides;
    struct point vertex[20];                // No more than 20 sided polygon
    float (*perimeter)(struct polygon * p);
};

struct polygon * polygon_init(int sides)
{
    struct polygon *poly;
    poly = malloc(sizeof *poly);
    poly->sides = sides;
    return poly;
}

void polygon_destroy(struct polygon * poly)
{
    free(poly);
}

float distance(struct point p1, struct point p2)
{
    return sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y));
}

// Assuming points are ordered ;-)
float perimeter(struct polygon * poly)
{
    float p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < poly->sides - 1; i++)
        p += distance(poly->vertex[i], poly->vertex[i+1]);
    return p + distance(poly->vertex[poly->sides - 1], poly->vertex[0]);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct polygon *p1 = polygon_init(3);
    struct point t[3] = { {0, 0}, {.5, 1}, {1, 0}};
    memcpy(p1->vertex, t, sizeof(t));
    p1->perimeter = &perimeter;
    printf("perimeter = %.2f\n", p1->perimeter(p1));
    polygon_destroy(p1);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can notice, I use a pointer to function to assign a "custom" function to calculate the perimeter (`p1->perimeter = &perimeter;`). With that I can "abstract" the call based on the struct assigned to `p1` .

But as noticeable, I pass the reference to struct itself as parameter to the `perimeter()` function as `p1->perimeter(p1)`, and this looks pretty much redundant.

I would like to know if there is a way to call `p1->perimeter()`, instead the call above and inside `perimeter()` function it would automagically (know that I'm referencing `p1`), said that it would calculate the perimeter of `p1` itself.

In a single phrase:  I'm trying to fake the behavior of class methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic solution is not to expose the function pointer to the end user, but instead to use a regular function call which does the pointer lookup internally.

```
float polygon_perimeter(struct polygon *p)
{
    return p->perimeter(p);
}
```

This is nice because it parallels `polygon_init()` and `polygon_destroy()`: all the functions are outside the "class" rather than this particular one being called via a member pointer just because it's polymorphic.

It also avoids leaking the internals of `struct polygon` to users. There are a lot of benefits if you require all access to a "class" to be done via an opaque pointer and a library of function calls. No members accessed directly, so the layout of the `struct` can change freely without risking API breakage.

If you go that route then you can completely hide its internals by only providing an empty forward declaration in `polygon.h`:

```
// polygon.h
struct polygon;
```

Comment: in this case we still need to pass the polygon struct to the function. While I agree that this is a more idiomatic way in C language, I'm looking (for sake of learn) if possible to call `mypoly->perimeter()` and get the result.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know if there is a way to call `p1->perimeter()`,
>   instead the call above and inside `perimeter()` function it would
>   automagically (know that I'm referencing `p1`), said that it would
>   calculate the perimeter of `p1` itself.

C does not provide any satisfactory way to convey the object for `perimeter()` to operate upon other than via a function argument.  There is a variety of mechanisms by which you could store a pointer to the `struct polygon` somewhere that the function knows to look for it, but these are all messy and / or not thread-safe, and all of them require some kind of operation or extra code in addition to the function selection and function call.

The `->` operator simply does not convey any information about its (left) operand into its result, and even if it did, C function call expressions convey information to the called function only via function arguments.

@JohnKugelman's answer already presents the idiomatic C approach to this kind of problem: pass the object to operate upon as an argument.  One generally does that *instead of* selecting the function via a member of the operand object, and in that way avoids the redundancy you pointed out in the question.

Going in the opposite direction, then, there are some fun games you can play in C11 and later with using [generic selection](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.1.1) to choose the function to call based on the type of the argument.  One typically wraps that in a generic macro.  Perhaps that would reduce the importance to you of recording functions as members of the objects on which they are supposed to operate.  For example:

```
#define perimeter(x) _Generic((x),          \
    struct circle *:   circle_perimeter,    \
    struct polygon *:  poly_perimeter,      \
    struct path *:     path_perimeter)(x)
```

Then when you invoke `perimeter(a_shape_pointer)`, you call the function that corresponds to the type of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize it in polygon_init:

```
poly->perimeter = perimeter;
```

If you're object interfaces get large though, you may wish to implement a proper virtual table (VT), which is just a struct of function pointers for a class. Each object then stores a pointer to the VT rather than all the functions individually, and there only ever needs to be a single const VT for any given class. That way the size of an object doesn't change as a function of how many virtual methods there are.